# Using SignalR as a replacement for $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, signalr, signalr.client

I know that there are known issues with using SignalR for huge chunks of data 64kb+ However I can't find any information on whether it is related to a case when I need to send large chunk of data to one specific client. So my question is whether it is appropriate to use SignalR for replacing $.ajax type of communication when dealing with one client. In my case I want both send and receive 5MB+ of data both from client to server and vice versa.

Thank you!